# If $S$ is a subset of $G$ with $|S| > \frac{|G|}{2}$ , then given $g \in G$ prove that $\exists a,b \in S$ so that $ab^{-1} = g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I was trying the following problem :

Let $G$ be a finite group. If $S$ is a subset of $G$ with $|S| > \frac{|G|}{2}$ , then given $g \in G$ prove that $\exists a,b \in S$ so that $ab^{-1} = g$ .

My attempt:

Let $S^{/} $ denote the subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$, then since  $|S| > \frac{|G|}{2}$ , by Lagrange's theorem, $S^/ = G$ , then again since $G$ is finite , I guess it follows that such $a,b$ exist.

Is my argument alright?
Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: No your argument is not correct. "I guess it follows that" is unlikely to be right! This question has been asked zillions (well, at least twice) of times before, but it's hard to search for it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$|gS| = |S| \stackrel{|S| > \frac{|G|}{2}}{\Rightarrow} gS \cap S \neq \emptyset$